# Token dependent API resetting with microservices

Tags: architecture, microservices

I have a micro service for authentication and authorization.
This micro service has to access a certain API to get information about the user that is being provided to the micro service.
How does it access it?

- It asks for a token using a certain set of credentials, which is unique
- It makes the needed requests (if needed, then multiple, using the same token)
- If the service asks for a new token, the last one is invalid
- The act of refreshing is performed but a cron job on the micro service that refreshes the token every few hours

I want to make the service being able to scale out, the problem is that if I scale it out, then each instance of the micro service will try manage the token by itself, and this is bad, there will be collusion in the current way of managing it.

I thought about how should I do it and came up with the following way:

- Some sort of DB (might be redis or something like that) that holds the current token
- A single instance micro service that is responsible for updating the token
- A micro service that is caple of scale-out and is responsible for retrieving the current token
- Getting the token for the auth service will go through the service that retrieves the current token

My problem with this approach is that it looks to me as if I'm making things much harder than they should be... I'm creating two additional different micro services just to manage the token for a certain API, it looks like a pretty small problem that shouldn't take so much to solve...

I would like to hear from anyone who had a similar problem, how they solved it while keeping it as simple as possible, while being able to manage a scale out to handle a lot of traffic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right , you are making things over complicated.

**Basic Authentication and Authorization**

In Modern Microservices architecture (or in general) we try to avoid writing our own Authentication/Authorization services from scratch. We leverage existing third party providers like Auth0.com, Azure AD, Okta etc. The reason there are many pieces need to be understood. If you don't understand auto2.0, OpenID Connect, JWT, ID_Token , Access_token , Refresh Token then first thing you should need to understand. You can write your own service as well but you really need to understand those things.

**How It works ?**

OpenID connect is the way we use authenticate now and is the modern way. In simple words OpenID connect (OIDC) providers like auth0.com would give you service for Authentication/Authorization that you can integrated in your service. Generally when you use OIDC the external service issue you JWT (Json web token with payload) tokens like access_token (to access resources and claims), ID_token (tell who the user is) , refresh_token (to refresh the access token) . When your user logs in the external service will provide access token. Your user will provide this access token with every request and your microserice(s) will verify this token everytime. This token is unique token and only your external service can verify this. Generally your Gateway microservice verify this token 
and then pass the request to respective microservice.

I would suggest to go through this documentation , [How Auth Works!](https://auth0.com/docs/videos/get-started/04_01-authenticate-how-it-works)

**Writing your own**

You can write your own as well. Your microservice will issue JWT token. Since JWT tokens are statefull meaning they do have everything to be authenticated so this solutions scales very well. Even if you have multiple instances , each service can verify and issue token without any problem. Each microserivce or your gateway service (or both) can verify the JWT token.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the question I'm asking is a bit different.
I have to rely on some private API to authenticate users.
While using this API, I have to use the tokens he generates, that is where the problem is.
I'm not trying to authenticate micro services between each other, I'm trying to find a way to refresh the token I'm generating from the private external API that I'm using.

Comment: What sort of token is it and I don't understand why would be a collusion in case you have 2 instance of microserivices? Shouldn't the token be unique for each user ? and currently where do you save/keep it ?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think its just some kind of a string representing uuid.
The token is unique for each set of credentials, meaning that multiple instances of my micro service can make multiple requests using the same token.
But if I try to generate a new one, the previous one is not usable any more and all the micro services have to use the new one.

Each token is saved on the micro service itself, but even if it wasn't the case, it would still collide with each other if one was trying to use it and the other to update.

Comment: if they are temporary token.  after generating them you can save them in cookie or with client. instead of microservices keeping them the client should carry them. so each time same token is passed by  client to each service.  this is generally we do in authentication in microservices scenario. you find any problems with that?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I cant create more than one token. I have one set of credentials, which means that I can only have one token in any time. And even if I get another set of credentials, I would need a new set for each instance of the micro service, its not going to work this way.

Comment: Like you mentioned you may be using shared db like redis to make it work consistently.  Having this approach you must be able to scale out.